# Reload TableView data after poping up viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a following set up:

The third view controller is a push segue where I want to insert all client informations. After I click "Dodaj" it saves all data into CoreData and pops the current view. Unfortunatelly it doesn't reload data in TableViewController. If I go back and click again on menu to get to the TableViewController data are reloaded.

I need it to reload before the last ViewController pops. Any help?

I've already tried

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

to pop view controller. I don't know how to reload data using `[self.tableView reloadData]` in another viewcontroller. Please help!

Best, Bartosz

Comment: How are you saving the data?  How are you setting the data source?

Answer (score 2):

If you always need to reload data in a tableview in any view controller, the easiest is to add `[self.tableView reloadData]` in `viewWillAppear`.

If you want to selectively reload data, find out more on using delegates.